# Разбор причастий по составу: увиденный и обиженный

Tags: морфемный-разбор

На сервисах [Разбор по составу слова «увиденный» | vnutrislova.net](http://vnutrislova.net/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80/%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%83/%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) и [обиженный - разбор слова по составу (морфемный разбор) | morphemeonline.ru](http://morphemeonline.ru/%D0%9E/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) дается **одинаковый морфемный разбор** причастий  (причем эти сайты не исключение):  **у/вид/енн/ый, обиж/енн/ый.**

**Это правильно или нет?** Как можно обосновать правильный ответ?

Comment: А что именно вам кажется сомнительным? На сайте, о котором вы говорите, я увидел только разбор причастия "у/вид/енн/ый".

Comment: Есть еще разбор у/вид/е/нн/ый. Как правильно?

Comment: @  Sibylla, ответ от Граммы.ру пришел. См. дополнение к основному ответу.

Comment: Серж, спасибо за ответ, пытаюсь понять идею такого решения, она мне не очень ясна.

Comment: – Sibylla, ответ, думаю, смогут дать только авторы грамматики-80.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В страдательных причастиях прошедшего времени пишутся суффиксы:

-нн-, если в глаголе прошедшего времени перед суффиксом -л- (или в неопределенной форме перед -ть) есть гласные а, я, е: разрисова-нн-ый (разрисова-л, разрисова-ть), вываля-нн-ый (вывалял, вывалять), настая-нн-ый (настоял, настоять), посея-нн-ый (посеял, посеять), разменя-нн-ый (разменял, разменять), ***обиже-нн-ый (обидел, обидеть), увиде-нн-ый (увидел, увидеть);***

-енн-, -ённ-, если в глаголе прошедшего времени перед суффиксом -л- (или в неопределенной форме перед -ть) есть гласная и: выезж-енн-ый (выезди-л, выезди-ть), выращ-енн-ый (вырастил, вырастить), выхол-енн-ый (выхолил, выхолить), напо-енн-ый (напоил, напоить); если причастия образованы от глагола на -чь: испеч-ённ-ый (испечь), прибереж-ённ-ый (приберечь), увлеч-ённ-ый (увлечь); если причастия образованы от глаголов, у которых перед суффиксом неопределенной формы -ти стоит согласная: привез-ённ-ый (привез-ти), принес-ённ-ый (принести), вымет-енн-ый (вымести).

Примечание 1. Причастия с суффиксом -енн- (-ённ-) образуются от немногих, древнейших по происхождению, глаголов на -чь и на -зти, -сти. Что касается глаголов на -ить, то от них, с исторической точки зрения, страдательные причастия производятся с помощью того же суффикса -нн-, что и от глаголов на -амь, -ять, -ешь. В древнерусском языке при образовании причастий от глаголов на -ить перед гласным и появлялось сочетание jэ, при этом j вызывал соответствующие изменения стоящих перед ним согласных. В результате возникли чередования д - ж (ходить -хоженный), с - ш (носить - ношенный), з - ж (морозить - мороженный), в - вл (выловить - выловленный), б - бл (долбить - долблённый), п - пл (купить - купленный), м - мл (выломить - выломленный) и др. Под действием этого же согласного (j) и изменилось в е. В результате переразложения (т. е. изменения границ между морфемами) в современном русском языке у причастий от глаголов на -ить выделяют вместо двух исконных суффиксов (-е- - суффикс неопределенной формы и -нн- - суффикс причастия) один - -енн-.

Примечание 2. От глагола жечь и его производных образуются причастия с помощью суффикса -енн-; ср.: жжённый, зажжённый, нажжённый, обожжённый, пожжённый, подожжённый, прижжённый, разожжённый, сожжённый (но: выжженный).

[Культура письменной речи. РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК...](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.34)

**

### Дополнение

**Ответ Граммы.ру**

На сайте портала допущена ошибка. 
Корректной является трактовка в "Русской грамматике" (1980): глаголы на -ать, -ять образуют причастия при помощи суффикса -нн- от основы инфинитива (прошедшего времени); глаголы на -ить, -еть (с некорневым -и-, -е-, которые отпадают при образовании страдательного причастия прошедшего времени, и с чередованием согласных) - при помощи суффикса -енн- от основы настоящего времени. 
Исключением является глагол "видеть" и его префиксальные производные, у которых причастие образуется так же, как у глаголов на -ать, -ять, то есть при помощи суффикса -нн- от основы инфинитива (прошедшего времени).

Comment: Серж, В Грамматике 80 дается разбор: увид/е/нн/ый, но обиж/енн/ый. Объясняется разными схемами образования: увидел - увиденный (от основы прошедшего времени) и обидят - обиженный (от основы настоящего времени). Объяснение не очень понятное, а на практике мы встречаемся с разными схемами разбора для "увиденный"

Comment: @– Sibylla, Грамма приводит материалы из книги Валгина Н.С., Светлышева В.Н. Орфография и пунктуация: справочник.- М.: "Неолит", 2001

Comment: Я посмотрю в других источниках.

Comment: Некоторые авторы выделяют суффиксы: анн-янн. Видимо, разная классификация.

Comment: Серж, здесь надо искать информацию в академических источниках, иначе не докажешь, что именно в данном учебнике  разбор правильный. Я пока связываю разные варианты разбора двух этих причастий с чередованием согласных в основе в слове "обиженный", но это только версия.

Comment: Вы правы. Но Грамматика-80 тоже академический источник.

Comment: В Грамматике-80 дан разный разбор, но мало что объясняется, поэтому  народ недоволен.  Вот,  например, письмо от искателя правды: "Я добралась до Грамматики-80 ( § 1585). Ответа на вопрос, почему причастия от префиксальных глаголов кл.  2, мотивированных глаголом "видеть", образуются от основы инфинитива/формы прошедшего времени с помощью -нн-, а причастие "обиженный" образуется от основы настоящего времени, я так и не нашла. В общем, вопросы пока остаются".

Comment: @Sibylla, я просматриваю сейчас Грамматику-80, но, честно, говоря, ни "увиденный", ни "обиженный" я там не нашел.

Comment: У меня бумажная  "Краткая русская грамматика" 1990, Белоусов и др,, под ред. Шведовой и Лопатина.§ 301, а тема называется "Причастие".  Там написано: Суффиксальный морф ЕНН используется при образовании страд. прич. прош. врем. от основы настоящего времени у глаголов пятого класса и группы 2. 2А, где имеют место те же чередования, что при образовании 1 лица ед. ч.: Получается обижу - обиженный. А вот глагол увидеть идет как исключение: не "увижу - увиженный", а  "увидел - увиденный".

Comment: Я нашел этот параграф. § 1585. Страдат. прич. прош. вр. образуются при помощи суф. -енн-/-нн- (фонемат. |oн1н|/|н1н|) и -т- (фонемат. |т|) и флексий прилагательного (о кратких формах см. § 1586). Суф. морф -нн- присоединяется к основам прош. вр., оканчивающимся на -а (кл. I, II, V, 1 и отдельные глаголы других классов: разыгра-л-а – разыгра-нн-ый, разрисова-л-а – разрисова-нн-ый, забрызга-л-а – забрызга-нн-ый, написа-л-а – написа-нн-ый, изгна-л-а – изгна-нн-ый). Морф -нн- выступает также в причастиях префиксальных глаголов кл. X, 2, мотивированных глаголом ***видеть (увиденный)***

Comment: Суф. морф -енн- присоединяется к основам прош. или наст. вр. на согласную. От основ прош. вр. образуют страдат. прич. глаголы кл. VI. При этом имеет место чередование конечных согласных: |к – ч|, |г – ж|, |б – б'|, |с – с'|, |з – з'| (см. § 1598, 1601): испек – испеч-ённ-ый, приберег – прибереж-ённ-ый; погрёб – погреб-ённ-ый, принес – принес-ённ-ый, отвез – отвез-ённ-ый.

Comment: Страдат. прич. гл. -шибить (у-, при-, за-, пере-, от-) – -шибленный (по образцу глаголов кл. Х вместо ожидаемого -шибенный; ср. исчезнувшее образование без чередования: [Скалозуб:] Воскрес и невредим, рука Ушибена слегка. Гриб.).

Comment: У глаголов кл. IV -вергнуть (в-, от-, по-, из-, с-) и -торгнуть (от-, ис-) образуются вариантные (высок. и устар.) формы причастия с морфом -енн- от основы без -ну-: изверженный, вверженный, поверженный, исторженный, отторженный.

   .

Comment: От основ наст. вр. страдат. прич. прош. вр. образуются у двух групп глаголов. 1) У глаголов кл. VII с основой наст. вр. на |т|, |д|; эти фонемы в причастиях чередуются с парно-мягкими: обре- т-ут – обрет-ённ-ый, привед-ут – привед-ённ-ый. 2) У глаголов кл. X, основа прош. вр. которых оканчивается на гласные |и| или |е|; при образовании страдат. прич. имеют место те же чередования, что и при образовании формы 1 л. ед. ч. наст. вр. (см. § 1599): закрут-ят – закруч-енн-ый, обид-ят – обиж-енн-ый, [...]

Comment: Так вот, нужно  кратко и понятно для школьников (а не для студентов) объяснить, как и почему разбираются два эти причастия. Какой вариант Вы бы предложили? Если можно, дополните свой ответ.

Comment: Sibylla, конечно, школьникам лучше объяснить доступно: так, как у Валгины.

Comment: Я обратился на Грамму, скоро они ответят, я дополню свой ответ.